# Is there a SUMIF function to sum across identifiers in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

Sorry if this is too simple a question, but is there a `sumif` function in python that will `sum` by identifier and category?  So in this case, I would like to have a function `sumif` which takes as arguments the identifier and the year and sums the amount.  For example `sumif('105','2006')` should return `1200`.

```
data = {'105':[{'2005': 500}, {'2005', 13000}, {'2006', 100}, {'2006', 200}, {'2006', 900}], '256': [{'2005', 5000}, {'2005', 800}]}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct data? `{'2005': 500}` is a `dict` but everything else is a `set`.

Comment: I'm new to dictionaries, so that's just the way I set it up.  Is there a better way?

Comment: there is a proper way :) it's always {key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}

Comment: Not a *better*, but a *correct* way: `{'2005': 500}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> data = {'105':[{'2005': 500}, {'2005': 13000}, {'2006': 100}, {'2006': 200}, {'2006': 900}], '256': [{'2005': 5000}, {'2005': 800}]}

>>> sum(map(Counter, data['105']), Counter())['2006']
1200
```

Therefore the definition of `sumif` would be:

```
sumif = lambda x, y: sum(map(Counter, data[x]), Counter())[y]
```

Answer (score 1):

if the parameters are constant and dicts have always the same size, it's something like

```
sum( d.values()[0] for d in data['105'] if d.keys()[0] == '2006')
```

there are many ways

a better question would be: where does the strange data structure (with singleton-dicts) come from?